# File manager undefined value for use unlink function

Tags: javascript, php

I added to my file manager a part in JavaScript to confirm the deletion. I have change my button onclick which calls the JavaScript function which allow to launch the deletion of the file, but I can't Forward file name in the JavaScript function. Actually in return I have: undefined in the variable.

So I can't recover the name of my file...

For use the function unlink I need ../CODE/image/name.mp3 for example

It's a part of my code tell me if you would like more tell me.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function valid(id) {

        //var nom='<?PHP echo $File;?>';
        alert('valeur :' +id);
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?'))
            //true
            {
            window.location  = "Gestionnaire.php?nom1"+id;
            }
            else
            //false
            {
            alert("Cancellation of deletion")
            }

    }
    </script>
```

```php
    <?php
    $adress="../CODE/son/"; 
    $desti="../CODE/image/";
    $dossier = opendir($adress); 
     while ($File = readdir($dossier))
          { 
           if ($File != "." && $File != "..")
             { 
               echo '<button onclick="valid()" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #ae0484" input id="'.$File.'" > Delete </button> => <a href="Gestionnaire.php?nom2='.$File.'"    ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #ae0484"> Copy </button> </a> =>'.$File.'<br>';
             }
           }


    if(isset($_GET['nom1'])) 
        {
          $File0=$File;
          $adress="../CODE/son/"; 
          $nom=''.$adress.$_GET['nom1'].'';
          suppression($adress,$nom,$File0);
        };
        
     function suppression ($adress,$nom,$File0)
        if ($File0 != "." && $File0 != "..")
          {
              unlink($nom);
              echo 'The file "'.$nom.'" has been erased !<br>';.
          }    
      };
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript part is missing an equal sign here:

```
window.location  = "Gestionnaire.php?nom1"+id;
```

It should be:

```
window.location  = "Gestionnaire.php?nom1="+id;
```

At the PHP side, you're using `nom2` as parameter name in the generated HTML, but you're testing for `nom1`.

So this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['nom1']))
```

will never be `true`.

Comment: `nom2` is for my function copy and thanx you for your help